# How to add two array together with key and values in codeigniter and insert into the table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays . one is manually created array and other is posted array. I want to combine the key with value. Below is my arrays. I want this as [1st_service] =>11 ,[2nd_service] =>12 .. etc.. and insert this into my table

```
    $services =Array([1st_service] => 
                     [2nd_service] => 
                     [3rd_service] => 
                     [4th_service] => )
    $servicecost = Array([0] => 11
                   [1] => 12
                   [2] => 13
                   [3] => 14)
```

Comment: use `array_combine`.

Comment: I used that one $result = array_combine($services, $servicecost);
        print_r($result); my result like this Array
(
    [] => 14
)

Comment: @Miya Please update your question with the full story, `estimation_id` input, and what you require as output because at the moment, the accepted answer does more than the question asks for.  Please include, in your question edit, a sample output query so that readers can understand what kind of query(s) you are trying to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you out.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$services = Array(
    "1st_service" => "",
    "2nd_service" => "",
    '3rd_service' => "",
    "4th_service" => "");

$servicecost = Array(
   0 => 11,
   1 => 12,
   2 => 13,
   3 => 14);
$keys=  array_map(function($value){
    return $value="name.".$value;
},array_keys($services));
print_r(array_combine($keys, $servicecost));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [name.1st_service] => 11
    [name.2nd_service] => 12
    [name.3rd_service] => 13
    [name.4th_service] => 14
)
```

Comment: Thank you!. It works. but have some more doubts. How to insert these into table. my table column name is  that key name.1st_service,2nd_service like. i want to add these values with corresponding column

Comment: Thank you :) but I want to create a array with other values together with this. then how to insert these $key_values in this array ....$arr = array('estimation_id'=>$estimation_id);

Comment: Based on switch statement i change the table and column name

Comment: so I cnt set array as $arr      =   array('estimation_id'=>$estimation_id,'1st_service'=>$key_value); I want to insert a row with posted estimation_id and these key_values

Comment: I solved these problem using insert and update query . anyways thanq so much :)